# Javascript in Drupal

Tags: 7, javascript

I was following this post on drupal.org - https://www.drupal.org/node/3075055

But I'm not getting the same result. I'm not experienced at all in javascript so maybe I'm missing something. Do I need to indicate where is my js file? The name of the js file is important?

My module code below:

```
function draws_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'bets_node_form':
      $form['field_possible_returns']['und'][0]['value']['#process'] = array('my_custom_process');
      break;
  }
}

function my_custom_process($element, &$form_state, $complete_form){
  $element['field_possible_returns'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 8,
    '#attributes' => array(
      'readonly' => 'readonly',
      'tabindex' => -1,
    ),
  );
  return $element;
}
```

The name of my module is `draws`.

My javascript file (in the same folder of the module file):

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.draws = {
    attach: function (context, settings) { 
      alert('Its working!');
      $('.field-name-field-bet-value').on('keyup change', function (){
        var bet_value = $('.field-name-field-bet-value input').val();
        var odd = $('.field-name-field-odd input').val();
        var result = (odd * bet_value).toFixed(2);

        $('.field-name-field-possible-returns input').val(result);
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Here are the field names of my content type `bets`:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: ok. I added this - drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'draws') . '/draws.js'); - to the second line of my draws.module file, right after <?php. It breaks the site :(

Comment: `drupal_add_js()` must be used inside a preprocess or hook function. In this case,  since it's a form, you'll want to use `$form['#attached']['js']` see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to indicate where is my js file?

Of course, js files do not auto magically get loaded.

You need to tell Drupal about them, There are various ways, see [Adding JavaScript to your theme or module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/adding-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module).

```
function draws_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'bets_node_form':
      $form['field_possible_returns']['und'][0]['value']['#process'] = array('my_custom_process');
      // Load JS File
      $form['#attached']['js'] = [
         drupal_get_path('module', 'draws') . '/draws.js',
      ];
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your code sugestion. Assuming the js file is being loaded correctly, and because nothing is shown in my field_possible_returns field, how can I debug this now? This field is a compute field.

Comment: After `attach: function (context, settings) {` add `alert('yay it loaded');` just to make sure it indeed loaded, remember to flush the cache.

Comment: Ok, I'm not getting that alert. I just double checked the $form_id and it is bets_node_form so that is correct. The field names are correct in the javascript? Is "-" instead of "_"?

Comment: Well if the alert isn't showing then most likely the js file isn't loading. You could also right mouse click and select view page source and then CTRL + F "draws.js" to see if the file is getting attached.

Comment: It seems that is: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../sites/all/modules/custom/draws/draws.js?qff4kv"></script>

Comment: When you click that src URL, do you see the alert in the code? Remember to flush cache after making change to js file.

Comment: If you want to debug JS file, see [Debugging JavaScript - Chrome DevTools 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8)

Comment: yes the code is there in the place you suggested.

Comment: maybe just have the alert only, get that working first and go from there.

Comment: `The field names are correct in the javascript? Is "-" instead of "_"?` should be the same as the class name you see when you right click and inspect element on the input field. Except in JS you add a dot at the front.

Comment: Maybe you have a syntax error further down, perhaps didn't close something properly. I can't tell since you didn't post your entire JS code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112072/discussion-between-zephirus-and-no-sssweat).